# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.log4j.net.JMSSink

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, environment-variables

I got this error when i run my Maven project.

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.log4j.net.JMSSink
>   maven

i had done environment variable correctly. like same

> **Environment Variables** -- under **User Variabls**-> i was set **variable name:** `path` & **variable value:** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin  and under **system veriable** -> i was
>   set **variable name:** `JAVA_HOME` & **variable value:** `C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131`

i am using eclipse Luna on that i had selected or checked in:

> window >> Preferences >> java >> Installed JREs >>
>   jre1.8.0_131(checked in)

anything i done wrong here can you please help on that?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the specified class is not in the class path.

Check your build path in eclipse and ensure that the required jars containing your class file are in the build path